# ng-class condtionally and $location path Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my site for example : `example.com`
and the conditions are  :

i want to add class when user in these location :
First condiotion: `example.com/#` wihch is user click on something without link like href="#"
 and
Second :`example.com/Cartable`

Here is my little code :

```
$scope.isActive = function (route) {
        return route === $location.path();

    }
```

**HTML**

```
ng-class="{cartable:isActive('/Cartable')}"
```

it's working , but how can i add two url , something like this:

```
ng-class="{cartable:isActive('/Cartable', '/#')}"
```

thanks

Comment: There is one interesting directive in ui-sref for such cases https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active

Comment: $scope.isActive = function (route1, route1) { ..

Comment: thanks for that @Rodion , yes i'm using ui router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices, either call the isActive function multiple times by adding a "or" condition as following:

```
ng-class="{cartable: isActive('/Cartable') || isActive('/#')}"
```

or changing the isActive function to accept an array:

```
$scope.isActive = function (routes) {
    angular.forEach(routes, function(route){
        if(route === $location.path())
            return true; 
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks but why should i use angular.forEach ? i didn't get this part !!
the function i wrote wotks fine with #/catable but not with /#

Comment: In case that you wanted to use my second approach, this means that the routes parameter would be an array. So, in order to check whether it matches your path or not, you have to loop through the `routes` and verify it. That's where the [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) came into play. If you don't want to, you can choose to use the first approach.

Comment: hi again , i used your first approach but when i click on something with '#' ng-class not working

Comment: Please consider to open a new question and describe your problem along with your code. So, it would be easier to help.

Comment: i asked again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140151/adding-class-in-multi-path-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, use the arguments

```
$scope.isActive = function () {

        for (var index = 0; index < arguments.length; index++) {
            if (arguments[index] === $location.path()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: many thanks can you tell me why should we use for ? the function i wrote wotks fine with #/catable but not with /#

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router, just do something like:

`li(ui-sref-active="cartable")
    a(ui-sref="routeName")`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active