# adding class in multi path with Angular

Tags: angularjs

here is my site for example : `example.com`
i'm able to add class when path is `example.com/Cartable` or path is `example.com/requester` with this code :

```
$scope.isActive = function (route) {
        return route === $location.path();
    }
```

**Html**

```
ng-class="{cartable: isActive('/Cartable') || isActive('/requester')}"
```

but for example there is a button in my html with

```
<a href='#'>Click</a>
```

that after click the url is:  `example.com/#`  so that's the problem , 
i can't add a class with this code :

```
ng-class="{cartable: isActive('/Cartable') || isActive('/#')}"
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: prevent the default event on the button so it doesn't add the `#` to url. Or remove the `#` from href. Show button code

Comment: updated my question , because our project is not finish yet some of our button should be like this, so you mean there is no other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change button behavior replacing it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;">
```

This will not cause url changing.

Comment: what about /# ? the problem is /#

Comment: can you add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)?

Comment: actually i don't know what's that for ?

Comment: change # to javascript:;

Comment: it will kind of disable the href ?

Comment: if will prevent link from changing. i mean javascript:; like in the answer.

Comment: got you , let me tell u the result tomorrow , thanks for sharing your time with me, it's 1:00 am :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `<a>` tag is inside your angular application, you can just replace the `#` in the href to be blank, and the location will not change (nor will the page reload).

```
<a href="">Click</a>
```

Comment: thanks , you right buddy, but i want to solve it with ng-class and function